# What does this error mean SECJ0222E in WebSphere Application Server 5.1

Tags: websphere, jaas

I found this on the [IBM support site](http://www-1.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=404&uid=swg1PK06349):

> **Problem**A JAAS LoginContext could not be created due to the unexpected exception. 
> **User response**The problem could be due to a configuration error.

but I have no other indication and can't determine the final reason for this error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Have you obtained the fix from
http://www-1.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=404&uid=swg1PK17150?